# How do I deserialize this JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have json that looks like this:

```
{
    "summary":{
        "somefield1":"somevalue1",
        "Twilio":{
            "field1":"value1",
            "field2":"value2"
        },
        "Tropo":{
            "field1":"value1",
            "field2":"value2"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to deserialize it into a java class that looks like this:

```
public class Summary {
    private String someField1;
    private List<Vendor> vendors;
}

public class Vendor {
    private String name;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}
```

So the Twilio and Tropo need to become Vendor objects in a list where Vendor.name == "Twilio" or "Tropo".

I'm sure jackson has the tools I need to work with this structure but I've been striking out with web searches.

Comment: What were your web searches? Also, you don't have an array, you have two objects. So you can't use a `List` (by default).

Comment: go through the basics here http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: Try to use maven plugin https://code.google.com/p/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with combination of `@JsonRootName` and `@JsonAnySetter` annotations. Your `Summary` class should look like this:

```
@JsonRootName("summary")
class Summary {

    @JsonProperty("somefield1")
    private String someField1;
    private List<Vendor> vendors = new ArrayList<Vendor>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setDynamicProperty(String vendorName, Map<String, String> properties) {
        Vendor vendor = new Vendor();
        vendor.setName(vendorName);
        vendor.setField1(properties.get("field1"));
        vendor.setField2(properties.get("field2"));

        vendors.add(vendor);
    }

    //getters,setters,toString methods

}
```

Example usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Summary.class));
```

Above source code shows below string for your JSON:

```
Summary [someField1=somevalue1, vendors=[Vendor [name=Twilio, field1=value1, field2=value2], Vendor [name=Tropo, field1=value1, field2=value2]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your objects:

```
public class Summary {
    private String someField1;
    private List<Vendor> vendors;
}

public class Vendor {
    private String name;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}
```

you have to modify your json. Actually a structure like the one you defined will be converted to something like:

```
{
"summary": {
    "somefield1": "somevalue1",
    "vendors": [
        {
            "name": "Twilio",
            "field1": "value1",
            "field2": "value2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tropo",
            "field1": "value1",
            "field2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

a list is defined between the square brackets `[]`, and in your case it's a list of objects `{}`.

I would change your json if you can, because the structure you post will be a mess to work with. The one I pointed out, that matches your java objects, is more clear.

Comment: We have to wait the op and see if he can change the json! :p

Comment: I do not have control over the JSON in this case and it is perfectly valid (although inconvenient for me) to have dynamic fields in JSON.  This answer IS how I would write the JSON to go with my objects but if that was the situation it would be covered in the most basic usage of Jackson and would not warrant a question here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON structure you've got would match this java structure where the key of vendors is the vendor name.

```
public class Summary {
  private String someField1;
  private Map<String,Vendor> vendors;
}

public class Vendor {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
}
```

---

The classes you've specified would support this JSON:

```
{
    "somefield1":"somevalue1",
    "vendors":[{
        "name":"Twilio"
        "field1":"value1",
        "field2":"value2"
    },
    {
        "name":"Tropo"
        "field1":"value1",
        "field2":"value2"
    },
    ...]

}
```

I don't think you can achieve what you want with jackson as the name is outside the "Vendor" object.

Comment: wouldn't Twilio and Tropo and ... have to be in a set of `{}` themselves?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Doesn't Jackson turn arrays into lists, so you would have to make an element inside summary that was like `"somefield1":"somevalue1", "vendors":{"name":Twillio",...},{"name":"Tropo",...},...}`?

Comment: yes, but the "Vendor" object has no name property in the JSON op posted

Comment: Then what is `private String name;` in the OP?

Comment: I guess he's somehow hoping it will magically be populated.  Idk.

Comment: What is not correct?  I'm commenting on ops expectations and showing how they are wrong.

Comment: The classes the op specified will match the json I've posted. I cannot see any list in yours. :)

Comment: I must stop posting when drunk :/  I'm voting you up :D

Comment: Ahaha! That's cool, tnx. I liked the "map" but I guess that also the json the op posted is not going to match a map because that will need a "wrapper" of the mapped objects. Like: `{
    "somefield1": "somevalue1",
    "vendors": {
        "Twilio": {
            "field1": "value1",
            "field2": "value2"
        },
        "Tropo": {
            "field1": "value1",
            "field2": "value2"
        }
    }
}`